# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'crew_ids' for column `uj`.`crew_uj`.`crew_id` at row 1

Tags: php, sql, laravel, pivot-table, multiple-choice

Laravel Multiple Choices Input Error:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'crew_ids' for column `uj`.`crew_uj`.`crew_id` at row 1
> insert into `crew_uj` (`crew_id`, `uj_id`) values (crew_ids, 15)

UJController :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'nama_event' => 'required',
        'venue' => 'required',
        'tanggal_show' => 'required|date',
        'fee_pic' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'fee_operator' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'fee_transport' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'notes' => 'nullable|string',
        'crew_ids' => 'nullable|array',
        'crew_ids.*' => 'exists:crew,crew_id|array',
    ]);

    $uj = new UJ();
    $uj->nama_event = $validatedData['nama_event'];
    $uj->venue = $validatedData['venue'];
    $uj->tanggal_show = $validatedData['tanggal_show'];
    $uj->fee_pic = $validatedData['fee_pic'];
    $uj->fee_operator = $validatedData['fee_operator'];
    $uj->fee_transport = $validatedData['fee_transport'];
    $uj->notes = $validatedData['notes'];

    $totalUangJalan = $uj->fee_pic + $uj->fee_operator + $uj->fee_transport;
    $uj->total_uang_jalan = $totalUangJalan;

    $uj->save();

    $uj->Crew()->attach('crew_ids');

    return redirect()
        ->route('uj.data')
        ->with('success', 'Data UJ berhasil ditambahkan.');
}
```

UJ Model :

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'uj';
protected $primaryKey = 'uj_id';
protected $fillable = [
    'nama_event',
    'venue',
    'tanggal_show',
    'fee_pic',
    'fee_operator',
    'fee_transport',
    'notes',
    'crew_ids'
];

public function Crew()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Crew::class, 'crew_uj', 'uj_id', 'crew_id');
}
```

Crew Model :

```
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'crew';
protected $primaryKey = 'crew_id';
protected $fillable = [
    'nama_crew',
    'divisi_crew',
    'nominal_fee'
];

public function UJ()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(UJ::class, 'crew_uj', 'crew_id', 'uj_id');
}
```

View create.blade.php :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="crew_ids">Pilih Crew</label>
    <select class="choices form-select multiple-remove" multiple="multiple" name="crew_ids[]" id="crew_ids">
        <optgroup label="Pilih Crew">
            @foreach($crewList as $crew)
            <option value="{{ $crew->crew_id }}">{{ $crew->nama_crew }} - {{ $crew->divisi_crew }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: what is crew_ids and what is its content?

Comment: crew_ids contains the selected crew_id from several crew data

Comment: crew_id is integer so you can not enter an array or what ever you have(which is very unclear) only a single integer is allowed, you could change the data type, or enter multiple rows

Comment: which part should i change?

Comment: ` $uj->Crew()->attach('crew_ids');` here you try to add an array to the integer field crew_id from crew, you need a bridge table to save crew_id for every member and the uJ

Comment: yes I already have crew_uj table which contains crew_id and uj_id

Comment: so why do you try to add the multiple crew_ids to crew you need to add the to the bridge table?

Comment: because I use the input data for a detailed view which will later be used as a report

Comment: you can not insert the data directlys, as you already noticed,  you insert it into the bridge table and then join them together for the report, that is how bridge table work

Answer (score 0):

You can [access the validated input](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#working-with-validated-input) as an array.

Hence this code would needs to be updated as:

```
$validatedData = $request->validated();
$uj = new UJ();
...
$uj->Crew()->attach($validatedData['crew_ids']);
```

---

[Syncing Associations](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations)

> You may also use the sync method to construct many-to-many associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table.

```
$uj->Crew()->sync($validatedData['crew_ids']);
```

Comment: if I use this code, an error appears like this : Undefined array key "crew_ids"

Comment: Can you check if the key is present in the `$validatedData` using `dd($validatedData)` ?

Comment: if i check using dd($validatedData) the answer is null, do you want helping me to solved this? can i up the code to github and you check?

Comment: Where exactly are you checking for `dd($validatedData)`. Check the contents of `$validatedData` after `$request->validate([...])`.

Comment: same answer, it null..

Comment: If `$validatedData` is being returned as null, try with `$uj->Crew()->attach($request->crew_ids);` or `$uj->Crew()->attach($request->input('crew_ids'));`